# Y values on each stacked bar using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, stacked-chart

Having a question on showing actual values on the chart. I do have a printed chart and need to show values of each stacked bar. How can I show these values?

I have tried `ax.text` function but it does not give desired result(see in picture). As the chart is normalized to 1 I need to show actual values of each stacked bar (at the top is the total number and it should be split to each bar-first bar should have 1 number 7, second bar should have 3 numbers where number 41 is split by the size of each color bar). Is it possible to do this?

My code how I come up with multiple stacked bars:

```
def autolabel(rects):
    # attach some text labels
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.text(rect.get_x()+rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*height, '%d'%int(height),
                ha='center', va='bottom')

p = [] # list of bar properties
def create_subplot(matrix, colors, axis):
    bar_renderers = []
    ind = np.arange(matrix.shape[1])
    bottoms = np.cumsum(np.vstack((np.zeros(matrix.shape[1]), matrix)), axis=0)[:-1]
    for i, row in enumerate(matrix):
        print bottoms[i]
        r = axis.bar(ind, row, width=0.5, color=colors[i], bottom=bottoms[i])
        bar_renderers.append(r)
        autolabel(r)
    #axis.set_title(title,fontsize=28)
    return bar_renderers

p.extend(create_subplot(nauja_matrica,spalvos, ax))
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can show the values of each stacked bar with the `ax.text` function. There are few corrections to make to your code to nearly get the desired result. Actually, just replace the `autolabel` function by the following code:

```
def autolabel(rects):
    # Attach some text labels.
    for rect in rects:
        ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2.,
                rect.get_y() + rect.get_height() / 2.,
                '%f'%rect.get_height(),
                ha = 'center',
                va = 'center')
```

It will correct the vertical positioning of the labels and give:
[image: Staked bars with their values]

If you want to change the labels to get the unormalized values then there is a little more work to do. The simplest solution is to pass an additional parameter `values` (which contains the unormalized values) to the `autolabel` function. The code will be:

```
def autolabel(rects, values):
    # Attach some text labels.
    for (rect, value) in zip(rects, values):
        ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2.,
                rect.get_y() + rect.get_height() / 2.,
                '%d'%value,
                ha = 'center',
                va = 'center')
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you thank you so much!! You are a lifesaver ;)